# one page checkout method template

Tags: magento-enterprise, template

I installed one page checkout extension but I need to edit some of the templates.
I already found some of the templates that used in extension but I can't find for the payment

This is the code

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('methods') ?>
```

Does anybody know here where I can find this template? Is this a native template in magento?

Please. Thank you.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an external extension

Comment: Thanks. But my question was about the code includes. Anyway, I already found the template under checkout folder. Thanks!